# How to solve this terminated due to timeout in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

Can I get this problem of Terminated due to time out solved?

I mean how to reduce the complexity or unwanted code in order to solve the issue?

Here is my code:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,n,hit,count=0,p=0,t,tmp,j;
        int h[]=new int[100000];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        n=sc.nextInt();
        hit=sc.nextInt();
        t=sc.nextInt();

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
          h[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
          for(j=i;j<n;j++){
            if(h[i]>h[j]){
              tmp=h[i];
              h[i]=h[j];
              h[j]=tmp;
            }
          }
        }

        for(i=1;i<=t;i++){
          h[p]-=hit;
          if(h[p]<=0){
            count++;
            p++;
          }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Firstly : Don't use bubble sort. Use `Arrays.sort`. Much Faster.

Comment: If an answer worked for you, go ahead and mark it as accepted answer. Otherwise, comment on it that it didn't work. It helps you get the right answer quicker. Make sure you actually try the answers though.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the problem statement, the only thing which I can suggest is to **always avoid Bubble Sort**. It's complexity is `O(n^2)`, and probably that's what hindering you're time requirement.

Use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) like `Arrays.sort(h)`

Answer (score 0):

**The only problem I can see is you need to import the scanner before you can use it.** When I ran the code you provided it gave me a timeout because it couldn't locate the scanner, but when I imported the scanner it ran just fine, so I'm assuming that's the same timeout error you're getting. **Put this statement at the beginning of your code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

**The finished code should look like this:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int i,n,hit,count=0,p=0,t,tmp,j;
            int h[]=new int[100000];
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

            n=sc.nextInt();
            hit=sc.nextInt();
            t=sc.nextInt();

            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                h[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(j=i;j<n;j++){
                    if(h[i]>h[j]){
                        tmp=h[i];
                        h[i]=h[j];
                        h[j]=tmp;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(i=1;i<=t;i++){
                h[p]-=hit;
                if(h[p]<=0){
                    count++;
                    p++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
```